# How to add instaview, model, visualize in pdi-ce-5.0.1-stable

Tags: pentaho

I was downloaded new version of pdi from community site of pentaho [pentaho community edition](http://community.pentaho.com/)
using above link I downloaded pdi-ce-5.0.1-stable version. But when I run spoon file in linux environment then pdi editor does not shows any options like model,visulize it only shows Data integration. How I can add this two options in pdi-ce-5.0.1-stable version. And I also want to add instaview for mongodb, so how can I do this ?